# Retaining order of the xml elements between serialization and deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have generated a C# class from an Xml schema. This class is used in a tool to perform following:

1. Read an Xml by deserializing
2. Make certain changes to the deserialized object.
3. Write the processed deserialized object into an Xml by serializing.

Basically I fill some data in the xml.

I have problems in retaining the order of certain elements between deserialization and serialization.

I have sample code below. fPNodeTypeWindowField and fPNodeTypeClass1Field can appear interchangeably in two xmls. The order of these fields are not fixed in the Xml. I don't face any problems while reading the Xml while deserializing. The order of these fields follow the order mentioned in the code.

Is there any possible solution to retain order of these fields as in Xml?

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class FPNodeTypeClass
{

    private string helpTextField;

    private FpxFPTreeFPNodeTypeRootFPNodeTypeWindow[] fPNodeTypeWindowField;

    private FPNodeTypeClass[] fPNodeTypeClass1Field;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string HelpText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.helpTextField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.helpTextField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FPNodeTypeWindow")]
    public FpxFPTreeFPNodeTypeRootFPNodeTypeWindow[] FPNodeTypeWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fPNodeTypeWindowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fPNodeTypeWindowField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FPNodeTypeClass")]
    public FPNodeTypeClass[] FPNodeTypeClass1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fPNodeTypeClass1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fPNodeTypeClass1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out myself that order can be fixed while serialization. It can't be dynamic.